# Informatica using Oracle database

Tags: oracle, sql-loader, informatica

We are bulkloading few of our target Oracle tables.
Many of our tables had one column with datatype timestamp(6) with local time zone.
when we insert just the date value(mm-dd-yyyy) then target database is defaulting the hh:mi:ss to 11:00:00 PM.
But when we make the load type as normal then the it is inserting 12:00:00 AM in hh:mi:ss part.
Could someone explain why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm going to take a guess and say your ETL server's datetime is one hour different to the Oracle Server, or it's set to the same time but in a different time zone. I can't quite put my finger on the mechanics of this but it's worth checking if that's the case - they you can look into exactly why you're getting this effect.